# How do you sum a column of a database to display total ratings in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to make a ratings system. I'm using visual studio. The database has 2 tables, one table for all the music tracks, and another table containing the ratings, and is hooked up with an FK.

Here's my tables and columns
http://i.gyazo.com/fc5d042749c8c04fb2b9aa2b64831b0a.png

This is my current attempt and it's giving me an error

```
SELECT DISTINCT Track.TrackId, SUM(Ratings.rating) AS average, Track.Name, Ratings.trackid
FROM Track
INNER JOIN Ratings
ON Track.TrackId = Ratings.trackid
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Track.TrackId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use aggregation functions, then you generally want a `group by`.  Without the `group by`, the query will return only one row.

```
SELECT t.TrackId, SUM(r.rating) AS average, t.Name
FROM Track t INNER JOIN
     Ratings r
     ON t.TrackId = r.trackid
GROUP BY t.TrackId, t.name;
```

In addition, I made the following changes:

- Removed `distinct` from the `select`.  This is almost never needed for an aggregation query.
- Added table aliases that are abbreviations of the table names, to make the query more readable.
- Removed `Ratings.TrackId` from the `select` statement.  It is redundant, because it is the same as `Track.TrackId`.
- Added a `group by` statement.

Comment: This worked for me flawlessly man, I appreciate it. But might you know how I would display the top 10 highest SUM?

Comment: You would add `order by average desc limit 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are using either a `sum, avr, min or max, etc.` functions you have to use Group by that is the law..

What you need to do first is SUM the ratings by track and then joining those later with your track table, something like this:

```
SELECT T.TrackId, SUM(R.rating) AS average, T.Name
FROM Track T
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT TrackId, SUM(Ratings.rating) AS average
FROM Ratings Group By TrackId ) R
ON T.TrackId = r.TrackId
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `distinct`. It doesn't do the same thing as `Group By`.

In SQL-think, what you're trying to do is group all the rows by Trackid, and average the rating in each group which you do like this:

```
SELECT Track.TrackId, AVG(1.0000 * Ratings.rating)  AS average
FROM Track
JOIN Ratings ON Track.TrackId = Ratings.trackid
Group By Track.TrackId
```

But, you're also trying to pick up the Name at the same time. Doing that at that same time as a group by isn't as straightforward in SQL as you might wish. A 'correct' way is something like:

```
SELECT 
    Track.TrackId, 
    Average, 
    Name
FROM Track
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TrackId, AVG(1.0000 * Ratings.rating)  AS average
    FROM Ratings 
    Group By TrackId
    ) R
ON Track.TrackId = R.trackid
```

Comment: Why is taking `Track.Name` at all confusing?  Just add it to the `group by`, assuming that `trackid` is a primary/unique key on `Track` (a very reasonable assumption).

Comment: Agreed, I'd go with your GROUP BY t.TrackId, t.name in most cases